# Create not routed call from asterisk

Tags: asterisk, phone-call, agi

I can use `.call` files to create outgoing calls from asterisk trunk `TRNK`

```
cat /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/tmp6Rn2aM.call
Channel: IAX2/TRNK/12345
Application: Playback
```

It works perfectly, but this calls not routed through `AGI` interface (I suppose because they are not routed internally in asterisk). 
So is it possible to create call using call file that will be incoming (or not yet routed) in some trunk(or in some context), and Asterisk will try to route it and will make route request to `AGI` ?

Comment: So where is question? If you need AGI, use AGI.

Answer (score 0):

Make call to extension, then Asterisk will use extension matching and run AGI when necessary.

EDIT:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out

> If the call answers, connect it here:
>
> ```
> Context: <context-name> Context in extensions.conf
> Extension: <ext> Extension definition in extensions.conf
> Priority: <priority> Priority of extension to start with
> Set: Set a variable for use in the extension logic (example: file1=/tmp/to ); in Asterisk 1.0.x use 'SetVar' instead of 'Set'
> Application: Asterisk Application to run (use instead of specifiying context, extension and priority)
> Data: The options to be passed to application
> ```

Comment: seems like this is what I need, any example or link please?